# How to ignore empty columns in a dataframe?(Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to ignore empty columns in a dataframe.

For Example:

sample.csv

```
Id  Name  Address    Contact   Item   Rate Qty  Price
1   Mark  California 98429102  Shirt  57    2    8
2   Andre Michigan   92010211
```

I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df = df.fillna('')

df.to_csv('sample.txt',sep='*',index=False, header=False)
```

The sample.txt looks like

```
1*Mark*California*98429102*Shirt*57*2*8
2*Andre*Michigan*92010211****
```

I want to remove the empty columns here. The sample.txt should look like this:

```
1*Mark*California*98429102*Shirt*57*2*8
2*Andre*Michigan*92010211
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The format of the output file is like that.

Comment: That looks like a badly specified format. I don't think pandas will help you here. You'll probably have to do some post-processing on the text file directly.

Comment: At best you could split the dataframe in 2 (with a boolean mask like `df['item'].isna()`) and write 2 separate CSV files.

Comment: I need to specify all data in a single txt file

Comment: Another solution would be to replace (consecutive) white space in the original file with stars. Using pandas is a mistake, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
sep = '*'
(
    df
    .applymap(str)
    .apply(
        # Removes all empty fields
        # axis=1, func=lambda s: sep.join(el for el in s if el)
        # Removes trailing fields
        axis=1, func=lambda s: sep.join(s).strip('*')
    )
    .to_csv('sample.txt', index=False, header=False)
)
```

Comment: This removes empty elements from all the fields. I just want to remove trailing fields.

Comment: @Atom Indeed. See update. Rather minor. Any question ?

Comment: Ok @Jaroslav. As long as it derives from [K&R's style (or 1TBS)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#K&R_style), I am okay with it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a memory buffer and `strip()`

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""1*Mark*California*98429102*Shirt*57*2*8
2*Andre*Michigan*92010211****"""), sep="*", header=None)

with open("sample.csv", "w") as f: 
    f.write("\n".join([l.strip("*") for l in df.to_csv(sep="*",header=None, index=None).split("\n")]))

with open("sample.csv") as f: print(f.read())
```

#### output

```
1*Mark*California*98429102*Shirt*57.0*2.0*8.0
2*Andre*Michigan*92010211
```